# Конструкция On E:Exception Do

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем смысл конструкции On E:Exception Do? Что такое E? Правильно ли я понимаю, что эта конструкция реагирует на любое исключение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E - объект класса Exception.
Да, данная конструкция и правда реагирует на любое исключение, дальнейшая обработка сводится к определенею типа (например,

```
E.ClassName
```

) и выводу сообщения (например,

```
E.Message
```

), либо иному действию.

Все исключения:

```
except
     On E : Exception do
       ShowMessage('Error: '+E.Message);
end;
```

Выборочно:

```
except
     // Ошибка ввода-вывода
     On E : EInOutError do
       ShowMessage('IO error : '+E.Message);
     // Деление на ноль
     On E : EDivByZero do
       ShowMessage('Div by zero error : '+E.Message);
     // Все остальное:
     else
       ShowMessage('Unknown error');
end;
```

Чем-то напоминает Switch/case+default

Answer (score 0):

дополню

если нужны исключение именно типа EOutOfMemory то

```
on E: Exception do // или on E: EOutOfMemory do
  if E is EOutOfMemory then
```

а если нужен целый все производные (напр EMyMemoryError = class (EOutOfMemory)) то так:

```
on E: EOutOfMemory do
```

Comment: не за что =)